# How to replace a part of a File Path in Python

Tags: python

```
import os.path
original = input(str("Filepath:"))
filename = os.path.basename(original)
print(filename)
target = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\transfer\filename'
path = filename.replace('filename', filename)
print(path)
```

I have a problem with getting new target path... I need to copy original file and paste it to new directory, that is always the same and the name must stay the same as it was in previous directory, I was trying to do it by code on top but it doesn't work, only thing I need to know is how to replace name of the Path file at the end. (Example: r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Directory2\***' and replace *** with filename of first file)

Comment: Why don't you just append `filename` to the string containing the target folder name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your code, if you want to change `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\transfer\filename` into `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\transfer\{new filename}` you need to call replace() function on «target» variable, not on the «filename» variable.

So your code would look something like:

```
import os.path

original = input(str("Filepath:"))
filename = os.path.basename(original)
target = r'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\transfer\filename'
path = target.replace('filename', filename)
```

On entering `D:\Documents\program.py`, the output is `C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\transfer\program.py`